# Groovy code to count the number of rows in a table

Tags: groovy

I am looking for a groovy code to find the number of rows in table.

```
def countRows = db.firstRow("select count(*) as numberOfRows from languages")
String count == countRows.numberOfRows
```

Comment: This works, just use `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a typo or the real code, but you use `==`instead of `=`. Moreover, `select(*)` is not a `String`.

```
def countRows = 
  db.firstRow("select count(*) as numberOfRows from languages")?.numberOfRows
```